# Is my django project consuming an unusual amount of RAM?

Tags: python, django, linux, ram, webfaction

This is hosted specificly on webfaction, the django project has a static only application but that's it. It also runs celeryd and memcached, but those processes have expected memory consumption.

**Some clues maybe to the problem**

Setting debug to true or false has zero affect on the memory consumption as it appears.

When I run apache2/bin/stop, then apache2/bin/start the consumption is dropped significantly, until I reload the site, then it goes back to this amount.

Here is the notable output from the commpand ps -u username -o rss,command

```
2120 /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
46408 /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
47124  /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
4800 /home/path/apache2/bin/httpd.worker -f /home/path/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

The number of instances are expected and normal, its just the memory consumption for the 2nd and 3rd that is bothersome.

The django project uses a bunch of 3rd party libraries and apps so maybe there is a memory leak? Other than that really it's just a bunch of queryset calls .. All the stuff that would consume a lot of memory like image re-sizing is all done in the template so it can't be that.

EDIT:
Here are the 3rd part apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'mptt',
'userena',
'guardian',
'django_facebook', 
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.admindocs',
'djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django',
)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: strange - personaly I don't think it's django..but could you post which 3rd-party-apps you're using?

Comment: I'll edit them inside the post, sec.

Comment: hmm, nothing unusual. I'm sorry, can't help you :-/

Comment: Install `htop` on ur server and observe the top memory consumption.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest that you use [Dozer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Dozer) to take a look at your memory consumption. Add the following to your wsgi.py:

```
from dozer import Dozer
application = Dozer(application)
```

and then load "http://example.org/_dozer/index".

Comment: Hi, using django with apache, dozer seems to be causing a run time error where it says: AssertionError: Dozer middleware is not usable in a multi-process environment. How can I work around this?